# google app engine python: how to extend ndb User class

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, app-engine-ndb

I'm using google cloud endpoints and want to be able to extend the `User` class so that a call to `get_current_user` would return an `AppUser` object with my own extra properties.

```
class AppUser(--?--): # what should i put here
    gcm = ndb.StringProperty()

    def send_notification(self):
         # do something with gcm ...
         pass
```

how can I implement such a thing ? and is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported officially, and I wouldn't recommend messing with it; there's a better way, just add a new `Model` and link it via the `user_id`, then you can do whatever you want with it.

```
class Preferences(ndb.Model):
    gcm = ndb.StringProperty()

user = users.get_current_user()
Preferences(
    gcm='',
    id=user.user_id(),
).put()
prefs = Preferences.get_by_id(user.user_id())
```

Comment: but what if `user_id()` returns `None` ?

Comment: Well branch out your code accordingly, if it's `None` then no need to retrieve `Preferences`; I would create that entity on user sign up, that way you'll be sure it exists on every subsequent login.