# Google Appe Engine and Flask - How to modify user model?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, flask-login

I try to move my Flask app into Google AppEngine, in fact, I start a new empty project...

I have these decorator:

```
from functools import wraps
from google.appengine.api import users
from flask import redirect, request, abort


def login_required(func):
    """Requires standard login credentials"""
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if not users.get_current_user():
            return redirect(users.create_login_url(request.url))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view
```

But I want to create my User Model, in "database" with some credentials, like: password, facebook id, and some others fields.

How Can I create a User Model, in Flask+GAE, and use in my Application?

Thanks!

Comment: I would just create a local User model to compliment the data, tie it with `user.user_id()`, like I suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022283/google-app-engine-python-how-to-extend-ndb-user-class/29025746#29025746).