# How to store data owned by User?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm learning Google App Engine + Google Cloud Endpoints + Objectify and I'm trying to understand how to create REST API which will let each particular user to save his data in the cloud.

My current struggle is how to store Entity owned by the User (`com.google.appengine.api.users.User`)?

So far I have endpoint:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "saveBook")
public void saveBook(Book book, User user) throws OAuthRequestException, IOException {
    if (user == null) {
        throw new OAuthRequestException("User is not authorized");
    }

    ofy().save()
            .entity(BookRecord.fromBook(user, book))
            .now();
}
```

Entity (in this context let's assume that `User` wrote the book):

```
@Entity
public class BookRecord {

    @Parent
    private Key<User> user;
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Index
    private String name;

    public static BookRecord fromBook(User user, Book book) {
        return new BookRecord(
                Key.create(user),
                book.getId(),
                book.getName()
        );
    }

    public BookRecord() {
    }

    private BookRecord(Key<User> user, String id, String name, String author) {
        this.user = user;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
    }

}
```

Problem arises from `User` not being an `Entity`, so I can't really use this solution and use `User` as `@Parent` directly. What is the general solution to solve this problem and store data owned by User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own `User` entity, this is where you'll store custom information/preferences for your app (as I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022283/google-app-engine-python-how-to-extend-ndb-user-class/29025746#29025746)).

You'll be using [`getUserId()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User#getUserId()) to tie it with the Google user, and from there on you're free to use it as needed.